# Not enough pins, looking for a "demultiplexer" that keeps state

Tags: integrated-circuit, multiplexer, pins

I want to control a simple display with a microcontroller. The display has 8 input pins, the microcontroller only 6.

Is there an IC that I can interpose that

- lets me set the state of each of its output pins and keeps it that way
- requires the least amount of input pins necessary

Something with a serial bus maybe?

I know that typically display controllers are used, but are there general purpose devices?

Comment: Try searching for "GPIO expanders"

Comment: This is exactly what I was searching for, thank you!

Comment: Ironically, the small MCUs are typically used exactly for this. They are called "[LCD serial interface](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/258)"

Comment: At the small scale, this is an 'addressable latch', like 74HC259.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you are looking for is a GPIO "expander" chip. There are many available, typically using I2C or SPI to connect to the microcontroller. The [Microchip MCP23017(I2C)/MCP23S17(SPI)](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20001952C.pdf) is just one example that I have used in the past. There are many others to choose from.

Comment: PCF8574 is another common chip of this type (I2C in this case), with a lot of resources available online about using them (they're particularly commonly used when interfacing arduinos to LCD modules, which has generated a lot of tutorial content).

Answer (score 4):

A typical shift register is 74HC595. What you pass is a byte containing 8 bits, thus 8 signals. You only have to store that byte (8 pins) in memory which only cost one byte.

For this you only need 3 pins. Except for GND/VCC you only need 3 pins.

You can even daisy chain 4 of them, controlling 32 pins (which cost 4 bytes to store) and still use only 3 pins (except GND/VCC).

Answer (score 2):

You most likely want either a "Shift Register" or a "Latch".

Shift registers allow you to load data serially, and are commonly used with MCUs - 74HC595 is a highly common one.

Latches allow you to use a control signal to hold a value. These are used a lot in memory access where you want to latch an address - for example if you want to load a 16-bit address from an 8-bit bus, you can load the upper half, latch it, and then load the lower half.

You could accomplish an 8-bit bus using two 4-bit latches. Each latch could have its own control signal using an additional 2 pins. That gives 6 in total. You could do it also in 5 pins by using an inverter such that one latch is holding its value while the other is transparent.

Comment: An alternative is PCF8574, an I2C 8-bit bidirectional parallel port. What you use depends if you prefer SPI or I2C.

Comment: Latched shift registers sound very useful as well, as they could be much faster. I accepted the IO Expander answer because in my use case I might have information flowing in the other direction as well, which many expanders seem to support.